# Handling out of bounds in Python/writing to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, xls

I am learning Python by writing some simple programs. I am trying to do the following -

I have an xlsx. It is of the format:

```
Team, Player
```

What I want to do is apply a filter to the field Team, then take a random subset of 3 players from EACH team.

So for instance, my XLS looks like :

```
Man Utd, Ryan Giggs
Man Utd, Paul Scholes
Man Utd, Paul Ince
Man Utd, Danny Pugh
Liverpool, Steven Gerrard
Liverpool, Kenny Dalglish
...
```

I want to end up with an XLS consisting of 3 random players from each team, and only 1/2 in the case where there is less than 3 (this is what I am struggling with).

I've started this out like so :

```
import xlrd, random, csv

# First open the workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\1.xlsx')

# Then select the sheet. 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# Then get values of each column. Excuse first item which is header
teams = sheet.col_values(0)[1:]
players = sheet.col_values(1)[1:]
filtered_teams = filter(lambda x: x[0] > 2, zip(teams, players))

teams = {}
for t,p in zip(teams,players):
    if t in teams:
        teams[t].append(p)
    else:
        teams[t] = [p]


samples = [teams[t] + random.sample(teams[t],3) for t in teams]
myFile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\1.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(samples)
```

The problems I am having -

```
    wr.writerow(samples)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Do I need to do some kind of explicit cast here ? How can I fix this?

Also, when creating samples, the list of all the teams/players if I use :

```
samples = [teams[t] + random.sample(teams[t],1) for t in teams]
```

it will work, but if I use :

```
samples = [teams[t] + random.sample(teams[t],3) for t in teams]
```

I get an out of bounds exception, since some teams do not have 3 players associated with them (only 1). To be exact, I get :

```
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

(which my simple Java brain has understood as an OOB).

How can I fix this/just get it to move to the next team at this point? Some kind of try{assignment} catch{move to next team} mechanism.

Can anyone offer any feedback/advice please ?

Thank you !

EDIT:

The errors being thrown were solved by Jean-François Fabre below, thank you very much. However, now, when I write to CSV, it only returns 17 rows ( there should be hundreds), and the format is completely wrong...I was hoping to write something like  :

```
Man Utd, Ryan Giggs
Man Utd, Paul Scholes
Man Utd, Danny Pugh
Liverpool, Steven Gerrard
Liverpool, Kenny Dalglish
```

but it seems to be just the players getting returned, without any real ordering ? Indeed if I change it to `random.sample(teams[t],min(2,len(teams[t]))` I still have 5/6 players returned per each team...

Any idea what my logical error could be here ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I don't think I am, I am just trying to print to CSV :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a somehow 2 (now 3 :)) questions in one. Since I have the answer for all of them, I'll jump in:

```
myFile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\1.csv', 'wb')
```

only works for Python 2. For python 3 you have to open in text mode (and possibly have to add `newline=""` to avoid spurious line blanks:

```
myFile = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\1.csv', 'w', newline="")
```

and for your other problem, just change:

```
random.sample(teams[t],3)
```

into

```
random.sample(teams[t],min(3,len(teams[t]))
```

so you're always within bounds.

Now, about the trashed output, you're creating a list of lists but you only write one row using `writerow`. This shocked my at first, but then I forgot :) Use `writerows` instead, or you'll get only one line of lists represented as strings, with brackets, commas...

*Another last issue*: the team information is missing from the file because you only generate player names.

To sum it up I'd rewrite the whole thing like this with some improvements:

```
samples = [[team] + players + random.sample(players,min(3,len(players)) for team,players in teams.items()]
with open(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\1.csv', 'w', newline='') as myFile:
   wr = csv.writer(myFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
   wr.writerows(samples)
```

Comment: @JeanFrançoisFabre thank you very much for the response. This solves all  errors with the compiler, so the program runs...but with unexpected results. I only have 17 rows, with hundreds of columns for each row, and they do not seem to be organized in any way. Any idea what may be causing this? I will update the question.

Comment: oh, I see, I think you need `writerows` not `writerow`. Try that, I'll edit my answer accordingly. Edited, I'm sure that this is the problem.

Comment: however, comparing to your expected output, I'm not sure: you always need the team name first, but you never output it in your `samples`. Maybe we should add the key to the values. And the expected output your mention is "team name, player" for each line, which is not possible with the current `random.sample` which issues 4+ players... So there seems to be other problems.