# Loading a random sample from CSV with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, random

I have a CSV of the format

```
Team, Player
```

What I want to do is apply a filter to the field Team, then take a random subset of 3 players from EACH team.

So for instance, my CSV looks like :

```
Man Utd, Ryan Giggs
Man Utd, Paul Scholes
Man Utd, Paul Ince
Man Utd, Danny Pugh
Liverpool, Steven Gerrard
Liverpool, Kenny Dalglish
...
```

I want to end up with an XLS consisting of 3 random players from each team, and only 1 or 2 in the case where there is less than 3 e.g,

```
Man Utd, Paul Scholes
Man Utd, Paul Ince
Man Utd, Danny Pugh
Liverpool, Steven Gerrard
Liverpool, Kenny Dalglish
```

I started out using XLRD, my original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442955/handling-out-of-bounds-in-python-writing-to-csv).

I am now trying to use Pandas as I believe this will be more flexible into the future.

So, in psuedocode what I want to do is :

```
foreach(team in csv)
   print random 3 players + team they are assigned to
```

I've been looking through Pandas and trying to find the best approach to doing this, but I can't find anything similar to what I want to do (it's a difficult thing to Google!). Here's my attempt so far :

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import csv as csv


columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CSV_1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        print(row)
        #for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value
        #    columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k
```

So I have commented out the last two lines as I am not really sure if I am needed. I now each row being printed, so I just need to select a random 3 rows per each football team (or 1 or 2 in the case where there are less).

How can I accomplish this ? Any tips/tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First use the better optimised `read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('DataFrame')
```

Now as a random example, use a lambda to get a random subset by randomizing the dataframe (replace 'x' with LivFC for example):

```
In []
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
df['y'] = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(str)
df['y'] = df['y'].astype(str)

df['x'].ix[np.random.random_integers(0, len(df), 10)][:3]

Out [382]:
0    0
3    3
7    7
Name: x, dtype: object
```

This will make you more familiar with pandas, however starting with version `0.16.x`, there is now a `DataFrame.sample` method built-in:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

# Randomly sample 70% of your dataframe
df_0.7 = df.sample(frac=0.7)

# Randomly sample 7 elements from your dataframe
df_7 = df.sample(n=7)
For either approach above, you can get the rest of the rows by doing:

df_rest = df.loc[~df.index.isin(df_0.7.index)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, very educational. It seems like both of these solutions will take, for instance, 70% from the dataframe - without ensuring that each team is represented in the output dataset. I want to ensure that 3 players from each team are returned. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Ensure by doing a subquery as in df['This'] this will also be highly efficient as DataFrames implement boolean masking for these tasks. That way you can build a DataFrame that has your desired features. Also consider accepting if it answered your question.